# IndexOutOfRangeException - Audio Spectrum Question

Tags: c#

I have no clue why the: float val = spectrum[i]; is yielding an Index Out of Bounds of the Array. Please help...! I am a complete beginner in this game.

```
public class InputScript : MonoBehaviour{
    void Start()
    {
        float[] spectrum = new float[256];
        AudioSource aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        aud.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, 44100);
        aud.Play();

        float maxIndex = 0;
        float maxValue = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i <= spectrum.Length; i++)
        {
            float val = spectrum[i];
            if (val > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = val;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        var freq = maxIndex * AudioSettings.outputSampleRate / 2 / spectrum.Length;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float[] spectrum = new float[256];
        AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.Rectangular);
    }
}
```

I should be able to extract the pitch of the input from a microphone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Side note: I can't see where you assign values into `spectrum`; according to your current code `float[] spectrum = new float[256];` is an array of `256` **zeroes**: `{0f, 0f, 0f, ..., 0f}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= spectrum.Length; i++)
// ----------------^
```

You're defining an array of `256` floats, which can be accessed like so:

- 1st element: `spectrum[0]`
- 2nd element: `spectrum[1]`
- 256th element: `spectrum[255]`

As your loop is testing to see if `i` is less than or **equal to** `spectrum.Length`, which we know is `256`, this has the effect of trying to access an element at `spectrum[256]`, which is out of range.

Change the comparison in the loop to be less than:

```
for (int i = 0; i < spectrum.Length; i++)
```

and this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a shot!

Answer (score 2):

In .net arrays have indexes from 0 to `spectrum.Length` exclusive:

```
for (int i = 0; i < spectrum.Length; i++)
```